# In Visual Studio code,how to stop execution of selenium webdriver code?

Tags: visual-studio

code

```
  import time
  from selenium import webdriver
  driver.get("http://www.linkedin.com/")
  print(driver.title)
  time.sleep(8)
  driver.quit()
```

output:
works fine

problem: 
when i try to re-execute it, it says CODE IS ALREADY RUNNING. anyone know how to stop that?